# Tkinter Canvas Freezes Program

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

For my class, I am creating a "Mandelbrot Explorer" program. There is one main issue: I lose control of the GUI (all written in Tkinter/Ttk, in Python 2.7) when actually drawing to the Canvas.

Here is my code:

```
# There is some code above and below, but only this is relevant

for real, imag in graph.PlaneIteration(self.graph.xMin, self.graph.xMax, resolution, self.graph.yMin, self.graph.yMax, resolution, master = self.graph, buffer_action = self.graph.flush):
    # the above line iterates on the complex plane, updating the Canvas for every x value
    c = complex(real, imag)
    function, draw, z, current_iter = lambda z: z**2 + c, True, 0, 1
    while current_iter <= iterations:
        z = function(z)
        if abs(z) > limit:
            draw = False
            break
        current_iter += 1
    self.progressbar.setValue(100 * (real + self.graph.xMax) / total)
    color = self.scheme(c, current_iter, iterations, draw)
    # returns a hex color value
    self.graph.plot(c, color)
    # self.graph is an instance of my custom class (ComplexGraph) which is a wrapper
    # around the Canvas widget
    # self.graph.plot just creates a line on the Canvas: 
    # self.create_line(xs,ys,xs+1,ys+1, fill=color)
```

My issue is that when run, the graphing takes a while - about 30 seconds. In this time, I cannot use the GUI. If I try to, the window freezes and only unfreezes once the drawing is done.

I tried using threading (I enclosed the entirety of the upper code in a function, `thread_process`):

```
thread.start_new_thread(thread_process, ())
```

However, the problem remains.

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to spawn a new thread, your thread should draw to an array or image object somewhere, rather than the canvas object on your GUI. Then, it can return the image, which you can draw on the canvas. While the thread is running, it won't bother your GUI this way.

Comment: @ChrisBarker I had considered doing that, but I want to keep the animation of it drawing (as it is updated every column). If it comes to it, I will resort to drawing to an image and then adding the image to the canvas, but I want to avoid that for now :P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute your loop "threaded" with Tkinter by implicitly returning to Tkinter's main loop execution after every point  your draw. Do this by using `widget.after` to register the next function call:

```
plane = graph.PlaneIteration(...)
def plotNextPoint():
    try:
        real, imag = plane.next()
    except StopIteration:
        return
    c = complex(real, imag)
    ...
    self.graph.plot(c, color)
    self.graph.after(0, plotNextPoint)
plotNextPoint()
```

This way, after each point you draw, the Tkinter mainloop will run again and update the display before calling your plotNextPoint function again. If this is too slow, try wrapping the body of `plotNextPoint` in a `for _ in xrange(n)` loop to draw `n` points between redraws.

Comment: You don't really need the `1` here (unless you're trying to throttle things back to 1000fps or less…). But otherwise, nice summary of the callback solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the cause of the problem—the GUI event loop is not running while you're busy running this code.

And you're right about threading being a good solution. (The other major solution is to break the job up into smaller subtasks and have each one schedule the next. For a more detailed overview of the options and all of the wrinkles, see [Why your GUI app freezes](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/10/why-your-gui-app-freezes.html).)

But it's not quite as simple as putting the whole thing on a thread.

Unfortunately, Tkinter (like many GUI frameworks) is not free-threaded. You cannot call methods on any GUI objects from a background thread. If you do, different things happen on different platforms and versions, ranging from blocking the main thread to crashing the program to raising exceptions.

Also, remember that, even without Tkinter, you can't safely share mutable objects between threads without some kind of synchronization. And you're doing exactly that with the Tkinter objects, right?

The Tkinter wiki explains one way to get around both of these problems at once in [Tkinter and Threads](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-threads.htm): Create a `Queue`, have the background thread `put` messages on it, and have the main thread check it every so often (e.g., by using `after` to schedule a nonblocking `get` every 100ms until the background thread is done).

If you don't want to come up with a "protocol" for passing data from the background thread to the main thread, remember that in Python, a bound method, or a tuple of a bound method and some arguments, it perfectly good, passable data. So, instead of calling `self.graph.plot(c, color)`, you can just `self.q.put((self.graph.plot, c, color))`.

The library [mtTkinter](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/mtTkinter) wraps this all up for you, making it *look* like Tkinter is free-threaded by using a Queue in the background. It isn't highly tested or frequently maintained, but even if it doesn't work in the future it still makes great sample code.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND: Almost, but not quite; it _wraps_ Tkinter rather than monkeypatching it. So you do it _instead of_ your normal Tkinter import. If you normally do `from Tkinter import *`, do `from mtTkinter import *`; if you normally do `import Tkinter`, do `import mtTkinter as Tkinter`.

Comment: This did work for me, but I have one (sort of) problem --- my previous set up calls `self.graph.update_idletasks()` after every x value (this is automated in my `graph.PlaneIteration` iterator). However, with the threading, it ignores this and is updated every point. This significantly slows the drawing down (takes over 10 times longer). I think this is directly an issue with the looping and threading. Can I fix this as well?

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND: Also, I believe the default queue-checking interval is something like 6 or 10fps; if you want to see updates more frequently, there's a variable you have to configure, which is explained in the read me.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND: You shouldn't need `update_idletasks` at all here. The problem is most likely that you're just cramming too much stuff into the queue and then trying to do it all at once; you might need to batch it up. Which might mean you can't use mtTkinter after all, and have to do your own queuing.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND: Also, once you start having to break your code up into tunable, unnatural batches of work for performance, you've done most of the hard work of switching to the callback design (as suggested by Chris Barker's answer), so you may want to consider that instead of threads.